# JQuery to switch option order on a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that I need to switch the order of the options in. I need to do it conditionally  (not every time) after the page has loaded and it makes sense to use jquery for this task.

Here's the HTML as it initially renders:

```
<ol class="choices-group">
  <li class="choice">
    <label for="first">
      <input id="first" type="radio" value="25.0">$25</input>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="choice">
    <label for="second">
      <input id="second" type="radio" value="50.0">$50</input>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="choice">
    <label for="third">
      <input id="third" type="radio" value="100.0">$100</input>
    </label>
  </li>
</ol>
```

I want the jquery to reverse the order of the elements so it looks like this:

```
<ol class="choices-group">
  <li class="choice">
    <label for="third">
      <input id="third" type="radio" value="100.0">$100</input>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="choice">
    <label for="second">
      <input id="second" type="radio" value="50.0">$50</input>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="choice">
    <label for="first">
      <input id="first" type="radio" value="25.0">$25</input>
    </label>
  </li>
</ol>
```

In this example there were three options, but it may be any number between 1 and 7.

Can anyone see a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$(".choices-group").html($(".choice").get().reverse());
```

See a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/epignosisx/bX3Kf/

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for the fiddle too.

Answer (score 1):

I would do an `$.each()` to get the elements in the `ol`,  reverse the order then use the `$.html()` to rewrite the ol

Please see the [jquery manual here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) for an example of this.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fairly simply. I would use Javascript object to help manage it where the key-part (property name) is the value used to evaluate the condition and the value is the reference to the DOM. Then you just append them back into `ol` in correct order.

```
var temp = {};
$.each('ol li', function(k, v){
   var $this = $(v);
   temp[$this.attr('someAttribute')] = $this;
});

/*some sorting logic and appending them back*/
```

This way, you can reorder them however you want and not just reversing the order.

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery:

```
$('.choices-group li').each(function(){
   $(this).parent().prepend(this);      
});​​​​​​
```

See  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MkMnx/5)

But faster would be to use pure javascript method as:
ObjetNode.insertBefore(NewNode,NodePosition);